# How to pick up item in range of player in third person?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my player pick up an item when I press E and drop it when I press E again. I want the item to appear in the player's hand. The player should only be able to pick up the item within a certain distance. My current PickUP script is here and the destination is attached to the players hand.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public int number = 1;
    public Transform theDest;
   



    public void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E) && (number % 2) == 1)
        {
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            this.transform.position = theDest.position;
            this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;
            number = number + 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E) && (number % 2) == 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
            GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
            this.transform.parent = null;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
            number = number - 1;
        }
    }


}
```

I did some research but I am confused and having trouble figuring out how to pick up the item at a certain distance. I followed the script from a tutorial but they were doing a first-person game and used "raycast". If someone can please help me figure out how to pick up the item within a certain distance and can maybe even help me figure out another way to pick up the item in 3rd person I would appreciate it. I tried to clarify as much as I could but let me know if you need more information. I am new here and don't exactly know what to include. (I am using the Unity Invector-3rd Person controller Lite if that helps)

Comment: hmm, raycast is a ray, which you can shot from one position to a certain range. I think is is very useful and you should do it. You can also use physics.checksphere to detect the object

Comment: could you explain and go in-depth about it a little more? I'm not that experienced of a scripter.

Comment: You need 2 step, step one is to know what is your object, usually with raycast, you will find what is the position of the object, it means that you can access the object. The second one is that how to make your object follow your hand when you are using hand to pick it up. You need to research it your self

Comment: I did some research and so far I don't understand where to start or how to implement it for my needs.

Comment: You should usually go the other way round, instead of handling user input on all instances of your pickup rather have a pickup controller component attached to your player. Then you could simply make a [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) and check if you are hitting anything within the given radius

Comment: And in general do not parent Rigidbodies! Rather use [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a Circular player centric box collider with a certain radius and use Oncollisionenter and OnCollisionExit to know if the game object is next to the player

Comment: Thanks, I looked up on collision but decided to go for ontrigger. It works now.